# add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java how to add in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java when i mention in bash script it will prompt for  like bellow

More info: https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/java
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

how to write script for this without prompt us

Answer (score 3):

use **"-y"**

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java -y
```

Comment: Nice answer, but on a bad question.

Comment: @Grant Garrison Thanks :) I agree, the question needs some "adjustment"...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo | add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
```

Comment: before it adding to repository it will prompt. how to write script without prompt us